# Requesting review of proposed database for Project Billing

Tags: database-design, schema

I've had enough experience with databases to get me this far, but I was hoping someone could validate my design.
Once I have this confirmed, next steps would be to implement in some tool, and use forms to allow our team to enter time against projects and "automate" billing.

Very much appreciated any advice here.
[Link to diagram](https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/acc59468-894b-407c-8cb0-3cb31700cc0d)

The main piece I keep getting "stuck" on is the Purchase Orders. Not all customers give us POs, but those who do, we need to watch our consumption in order to request more funds ahead of time.

Thanks,
Chris

**Additional details**

- Apologies, I thought the link was public. This one should work: [LINK](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/032c2d06-4374-46a4-ba5a-b3d26b67e146).
- I am building an automated invoice generator. Basically want to input values for Line Item Details monthly, and all other data should be updated much less frequently.
- I'm not sure what else folks would need. As described, this is intended to be the schema behind some forms I'll use to create a project invoicing app (maybe in Powerapps). There is some additional context on the diagram itself, to give more info about the table relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Chris and welcome to SE.

Here are my 5 cents:

1. Your ERD is supposed to be derived from your logical data model, which models your business reality. Without the data model, full documentation of the business processes, the data dictionary, and thorough understanding of the subject matter, any analysis of the ERD is a futile (and dangerous) attempt.
2. Even if you provide all of the above, it would probably take a professional months to properly evaluate it. Data modeling and relational database design is a science and art that takes a long time to master, and to practice. I highly doubt that any professional data modeler will do it for free.
3. Following up on number 3, the only people who might offer their "opinions", without having all the supporting information, are typically the ones whose opinion you probably want to avoid. Be careful, or you might get what you ask for.
4. The data model, and the resulting database design, is the single most crucial aspect of your software stack. It will determine your data's consistency, the effort and complexity involved in writing queries for it, the queries' performance, its scalability, modularity, how much support and hardware it will require, and much more.
5. Unfortunately, it is also the aspect that is the hardest to correct
   after the fact, due to the dependencies which typically spread like tentacles all over the code stack.

From your question, it sounds like this is intended for a commercial business. 
My advice to you - hire or contract a professional data modeler / database designer, if you don't have the appropriate resources o. The long-term value your organization will get from it, will be many order-of-magnitude higher than what it will cost.

I know this is not what you came here for, but it is the best advice I can give from my 2.5 decades of experience.

Cheers

PS: The site that you linked to requires creating and signing in with an account. I doubt that anyone who doesn't already have one, will go through the trouble and the risks/hassles involved with volunteering personal details just to answer a SE question.